# Python how to write a mixed list to a csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a list containing a dictionary like:
`data = ['a','b','c',{1:'d',2:'e'}]`. What I want in the csv file is `['a','b','c','d','e']`.

I can do this by first convert the dictionary item to a list, replace it with the list and then write the modified `data` to a csv file. But what I need is a method that can write `data` into a csv file without changing it to `data = ['a','b','c','d','e']`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the dictionary values (`d` and `e`) sorted by key or value?

Comment: the values are sorted by key.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are different types in your list and you want to handle each of these type differently, you should try to use `isinstance(x, type)` see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', {1:'d', 2:'e'}]

def flattener(alist):
    flatten = []
    for i in alist:
        if isinstance(i, dict):
            for j in sorted(i): # Sort by keys.
                yield i[j]
        elif isinstance(i,str):
            yield i

flatten = [i for i in flattener(data)]
```

[out]:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

To get a list into a csv file, simply:

```
flatten = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
with open('out.csv', 'w') as fout:
  fout.write(','.join(flatten))
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the output order `'d','e'`, and determining the appropriate order depends upon the answer to @Tim's question.

Comment: but the OP can sort the flatten list later, no?

Comment: You can use `flatten.extend(i.values())` rather than looping over the items, if you want. This code makes a lot of sense as a generator function also, where you `yield` rather than append each value (and if you're in Python 3.3 or later `yield from`, rather than `extend`). The order of the dictionary values isn't guaranteed, but it may probably work for small consecutive integer keys as long as there were never been any other kinds of keys in the dictionary.

Comment: @blckknght, changed to `yield` generator.

Comment: @alvas: no, the OP can't sort later, or at least not without rewalking `alist`.  The sort is by key, but you only yield values, so the information isn't there to be used anymore.  You could address this by using `for k in sorted(i): yield i[k]` or something.

Comment: ah, sort the values within the dict, i thought he wanted to sort alphabetically at the end. so, yeah, use `sorted(dict)` would get sort-by-key.

Comment: Thanks. Since the dict is just the last item in the list. How about using `dict.values()`?

Comment: as explained in the comments, `dict.values()` wouldn't ensure that your values are sorted by keys. they might jumbled up because `dict` is unordered by default.

Comment: But can it ensure that the order the returned values are the same (assuming the dict is not altered)? `d={2:'d', 1:'e'}`, Then `d.values()` always returns ['d','e'], right?